# Only using one entire once

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My table consists of 100 different names, all unique and all have a primary key that is a number between 1-100.

How can start from the first one, and call a function for each name making sure it is only used once, once each name is used it starts back over at one, and loops 5 times.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: So, you want to call a function on every item in a table, in order, five times?

Comment: Can you add a column to the table that tells you how many time you have called the function on that row?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do

Comment: This question title makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

If all the names themselves are unique then you shouldnt have to worry about checking if the name has been called because its only going to exist once in your recordset.

If all you need is the name and the id for your function and your total number of names isnt too large (like the ~100 you mentioned) then it is easiest to just fetch them all into memory initially so you dont have to deal with a DB cursor or re-querying.

PDO Example:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

// fetch all records returning an array like:
// array($id => $name)
$names = $db->query('SELECT id, name FROM tablename')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
   foreach($names as $id => $name)
   {
     myfunction($id, $name); // call your function
   }
}
```

Mysqli Example:

```
$db = new Mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
$result = $db->query('SELECT id, name FROM tablename');

if($result)
{
  $names = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $result->free();

  for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
  {
     foreach($names as $j => $row)
     {
       myfunction($row['id'], $row['name']); // call your function
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

```
$this->db->select('id, name');
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
for($i =0; i<5; i++){
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    /* you can use $row['id'] and $row['name']
     and pass them as arguments your function 
   */
}

}
```

Comment: You might want to mention what database extension or library youre using there so there is no confusion... looks like CodeIgniter, maybe?

Comment: I have added the link to the database class offered by CodeIgniter. --regards.